# How to create column pairs in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as below. I want to create a column like this:

```
 d={
        'customer' :['abadia dos dourados','abadiania','abaete'],
        'seller':['montenegro','rio de janeiro','bauru']
    }
    
df=pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['customer','seller'])
```

Expected result like this:

[image]

I am using this code. But it doesnot seem same.

```
cols = ['customer','seller']
df['City_Pairs'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x:','.join([str(x) for x in zip(x.values)]), axis=1)
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: Looks like your dataframe is incomplete. quite some values from expected output arent present in the input provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the way you are constructing your concatenated string.  I've used an `f-string`

```
df['City_Pairs'] = df.apply(lambda r: f"({r['customer']},{r['seller']})", axis=1)
```

### output

```
            customer          seller                        City_Pairs
 abadia dos dourados      montenegro  (abadia dos dourados,montenegro)
           abadiania  rio de janeiro        (abadiania,rio de janeiro)
              abaete           bauru                    (abaete,bauru)
```